# How to use SqLite in Xamarin Froms?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

Everyone.

I am using SqLite in Xamarin Forms. For that I am using SqLite - PCL nuget. Now the problem is, It works fine in Android. But in UWP I can't Access database file.
I am using Common code for both Platforms. It is as below :

```
database = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "mydb.db"));
database.CreateTable<Item>();
```

The error I am getting in UWP app only.
[image: Error Screen Shot]

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/#Windows_10_Universal_Windows_Platform_UWP) contain clear instructions on how to do this in UWP

```
using Windows.Storage;
...

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileHelper))]
namespace Todo.UWP
{
    public class FileHelper : IFileHelper
    {
        public string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
        {
            return Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot Change Path?

Comment: UWP apps have different file system restrictions

Comment: Actually, I want to create database file at Shared Folder Location. Is it Possible?

Comment: I don't know, this sounds like something that is probably clearly documented and you might try researching yourself.  I just googled and came up with several informative hits.